# Conjunction Processing - Can this be improved/minimized?

Tags: javascript

Is there a ***better***, ***simpler***, or ***more efficient***  way to process the conjunctions to get the same outcome.
This will take in any coordinating conjunction ***listing type*** and get the outcome expected that is expected.

## Basically…

I have 3 functions that takes in any type of `and` - `or` coordinating conjunction and gives an output of what is intended.

---

## **Stage 1**

```
function {
    // Takes a sentence
    // Replaces `\r` `\n` `\t` and `\s\s` with ` `
    // Figures out which part of the sentence is the conjunction part
    // Places the conjunction in an array call foundConjunction = []

    // Nothing to see here - (Keep Scrolling)
}
```

---

## Stage 2

**First Function**

Counts number of whatever I'm looking for… **may come in handy in the future**… if I want to know how many ***words or phrases*** needs to be processed

**Example:**

4 `,` tells me the user has 5 items that he/she wants to chose from if he uses `, or`.

```
String.prototype.Count = function(find) {
    let Key = find.test(this)
    if (Key) {
    return this.match(find).length
} 
else {return 0}
}
```

**Second Function**

Picks a random number - used for when there is an `, or` -or- `word or another word`

```
function rand(min, max, interval) {
    if (typeof(interval) === 'undefined') interval = 1
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + interval) / interval)
    return r * interval + min
    //var a = rand(0,2)
    //var b = rand(4,6,0.0000001)
}
```

**Third Function**

Figures out what the heck you want.

```
String.prototype.conjunctionProcessing = function () {
    let andKey = /,?(\sand\s).*$/g.test(this)
    let orKey = /,(\sor\s).*$/g.test(this)

    if (andKey===true&&orKey===false) {
    let a = this.replace(/,?\sand/g, ',').split(/,\s/g)
        let orKey = /\sor\s/g.test(a)

        if (orKey) {
            for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
                let b = a[i]
                let orKey = /\sor\s/g.test(b)
                if (orKey) {
                    let c = b.split(' or ');
                    let d = rand(0, c.length - 1);
                    a[i] = c[d];
                }
            }
        }
        return a
    }
    if (orKey) {
        let a = this.replace(/,\sor?/g, ',').split(/,\s/g)
        let orKey = /\sor\s/g.test(a)

        if (orKey) {
            for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
                let b = a[i]
                let orKey = /\sor\s/g.test(b)
                if (orKey) {
                    let c = b.split(' or ');
                    let rIndex = rand(0, c.length - 1);
                    a[i] = c[rIndex];
                }
            }
        }

        let rIndex = rand(0, a.length - 1);
        let chosen1 = a[rIndex];
        let andKey = /\sand\s/g.test(chosen1);
        if (andKey) {return chosen1.split(/\sand\s/g)}
        else            {return chosen1};

    }
}
```

**Processing Time**

```
// Try any of these to see the outcome

// width and height
// width or height
// depth, width and height
// blue, width, and height
// gold, teal, or green
// hamster, cat or dog, horse and cow
// hamster, cat or dog, horse or cow, and mouse
// iPad and iPhone, Galaxy Tab and Galaxy Note 8, or Surface Tablet and Windows Phone

foundConjunction = ["blue, black or white, width and height, or background color"]
s1 = foundConjunction[0];
s2 = s1.conjunctionProcessing()

console.log(s2)
```

```js
String.prototype.Count = function(find) {
  let Key = find.test(this)
  if (Key) {
    return this.match(find).length
  } else {
    return 0
  }
}

function rand(min, max, interval) {
  if (typeof(interval) === 'undefined') interval = 1
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + interval) / interval)
  return r * interval + min
  //var a = rand(0,2)
  //var b = rand(4,6,0.0000001)
}

String.prototype.conjunctionProcessing = function() {
  let andKey = /,?(\sand\s).*$/g.test(this)
  let orKey = /,(\sor\s).*$/g.test(this)

  if (andKey === true && orKey === false) {
    let a = this.replace(/,?\sand/g, ',').split(/,\s/g)
    let orKey = /\sor\s/g.test(a)

    if (orKey) {
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        let b = a[i]
        let orKey = /\sor\s/g.test(b)
        if (orKey) {
          let c = b.split(' or ');
          let d = rand(0, c.length - 1);
          a[i] = c[d];
        }
      }
    }
    return a
  }
  if (orKey) {
    let a = this.replace(/,\sor?/g, ',').split(/,\s/g)
    let orKey = /\sor\s/g.test(a)

    if (orKey) {
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        let b = a[i]
        let orKey = /\sor\s/g.test(b)
        if (orKey) {
          let c = b.split(' or ');
          let rIndex = rand(0, c.length - 1);
          a[i] = c[rIndex];
        }
      }
    }

    let rIndex = rand(0, a.length - 1);
    let chosen1 = a[rIndex];
    let andKey = /\sand\s/g.test(chosen1);
    if (andKey) {
      return chosen1.split(/\sand\s/g)
    } else {
      return chosen1
    };

  }


}


foundConjunction = ["blue, black or white, width and height, or background color"]
s1 = foundConjunction[0];
s2 = s1.conjunctionProcessing()

console.log(s2)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: One way to optimize this is creating the regular expressions only once. You have some regexs being created inside loops, that should be constants.